# OCIDefineByPos extract NUMBER value via cursor in C++

Tags: c++, oracle, numbers, oracle-call-interface, sys-refcursor

Following on from [Call an Oracle stored procedure via OCI and return the results with an out ref cursor in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770846/call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-via-oci-and-return-the-results-with-an-out-ref-c) I want to extract a NUMBER column and store the result in either a double or long (truncated).

In summary, I am calling an oracle stored procedure via OCI using a sys ref_cursor to itterate over the results. I can already extract VARCHAR2 columns easily using a char[] however NUMBER columns are not working (I only need the integer component).

Table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE FXT_CON_RULES
(   
    SET_NAM VARCHAR2(12), 
    CC_TYPE VARCHAR2(8), 
    AMT_FLOOR NUMBER, 
    METHOD_FLG" CHAR(1), 
    BASIS_POINTS" NUMBER(10,1)
)
```

Stored proc is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FXT_TEST_CALL(CRESULTS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
sTESTQUERY                             VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
sTESTQUERY := ' 
    SELECT
    set_nam,
    cc_type,
    amt_floor,
    method_flg,
    basis_points
from 
    fxt_con_rules c';

OPEN CRESULTS FOR sTESTQUERY;
END FXT_TEST_CALL;
```

I have tried using SQLT_NUM, SQLT_INT, SQLT_VNU using variables of both long (also long long) and double however i've still not been able to get an integer value other than 0 out of it. 
Code snippet:

```
char set_nam[40];
double amt_floord = 0;

int answer = OCIStmtExecute(g_pOciServiceContext, pOciStatement, pOciError, 1, 0, NULL, NULL, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
answer = OCIDefineByPos(cursor,&pOciDefine, pOciError,1,set_nam,40, SQLT_STR, 0, 0, 0,OCI_DEFAULT);
answer = OCIDefineByPos(cursor,&pOciDefine2, pOciError,3,&amt_floord,sizeof(amt_floord), SQLT_NUM, 0, 0, 0,OCI_DEFAULT);

int blah = 0;
while ((answer = OCIStmtFetch(cursor,pOciError, 1,OCI_FETCH_NEXT,OCI_DEFAULT)) == 0)
{
    // longTest is always zero while set_name is populated correctly
    long long longTest = static_cast<long long>(amt_floord);
    blah++;
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated (apologies if i've missed something simple!).
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found using Oracle's supplied Number class.
    OCINumber numTest;

```
answer = OCIDefineByPos(cursor,&pOciDefine2, pOciError,3,&numTest,sizeof(OCINumber), SQLT_VNU, 0, 0, 0,OCI_DEFAULT);

long long longNum =  0;
OCINumberToInt(pOciError, &numTest, sizeof(long long), OCI_NUMBER_SIGNED , &longNum);
```

I've not found a way to supply a C/C++ integer/floating point directly to OCIDefineByPos but this will do.